# How to add a mouse hover tooltip on d3 radial component?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using `d3` to render a multi-radial components like below:

[image]

I want to add a mouse hover tooltips on each of the radial. but the path is rectangle which means I don't know whether the mouse position is hoving on each radial. So how can I add the tooltip on this component?

Below is the complete source code:

https://codepen.io/zhaoyi0113/pen/mpzPjw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can do that by select all the class and append a mouse over
>   function

**Add this on your last build function**

*to get mouseover on radial*

```
d3.selectAll('.bg').each(function(){
   d3.select(this).on('mouseover',function(){
     console.log( d3.select(this).style('fill') )
   })
 })
```

*to get mouseover on icon*

```
 d3.selectAll('.icon').each(function(){
      d3.select(this).on('mouseover',function(){
        console.log('class .icon')
      })
    })
```

```js
//based on https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1096355
 //apple design:https://images.apple.com/watch/features/images/fitness_large.jpg
 "use strict";

 (function(){
  var gap = 2;
    var innerRadius = 140;
    var outerRadius = 180;
  var ranDataset = function () {
   var ran = Math.random();

   return    [
    {index: 0, name: 'move', icon: "\uF105", percentage: ran * 60 + 30},
    {index: 1, name: 'exercise', icon: "\uF101", percentage: ran * 60 + 30},
    {index: 2, name: 'stand', icon: "\uF106", percentage: ran * 60 + 30}
   ];

  };

  var ranDataset2 = function () {
   var ran = Math.random();

   return    [
    {index: 0, name: 'move', icon: "\uF105", percentage: ran * 60 + 30}
   ];

  };
  var colors = ["#e90b3a", "#a0ff03", "#1ad5de"];
  var width = 500,
    height = 500,
    τ = 2 * Math.PI;

  function build(dataset,singleArcView){

   var arc = d3.svg.arc()
     .startAngle(0)
     .endAngle(function (d) {
      return d.percentage / 100 * τ;
     })
     .innerRadius(function (d) {
      return innerRadius - d.index * (40 + gap)
     })
     .outerRadius(function (d) {
      return outerRadius - d.index * (40 + gap)
     })
     .cornerRadius(20);//modified d3 api only

   var background = d3.svg.arc()
     .startAngle(0)
     .endAngle(τ)
     .innerRadius(function (d, i) {
      return innerRadius - d.index * (40 + gap)
     })
     .outerRadius(function (d, i) {
      return outerRadius - d.index * (40 + gap)
     });

   var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height)
     .append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

   //add linear gradient, notice apple uses gradient alone the arc..
   //meh, close enough...


   var gradient = svg.append("svg:defs")
     .append("svg:linearGradient")
     .attr("id", "gradient")
     .attr("x1", "0%")
     .attr("y1", "100%")
     .attr("x2", "50%")
     .attr("y2", "0%")
     .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");

   gradient.append("svg:stop")
     .attr("offset", "0%")
     .attr("stop-color", "#fe08b5")
     .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

   gradient.append("svg:stop")
     .attr("offset", "100%")
     .attr("stop-color", "#ff1410")
     .attr("stop-opacity", 1);


   //add some shadows
   var defs = svg.append("defs");

   var filter = defs.append("filter")
     .attr("id", "dropshadow")

   filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
     .attr("in", "SourceAlpha")
     .attr("stdDeviation", 4)
     .attr("result", "blur");
   filter.append("feOffset")
     .attr("in", "blur")
     .attr("dx", 1)
     .attr("dy", 1)
     .attr("result", "offsetBlur");

   var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge");

   feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
     .attr("in", "offsetBlur");
   feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
     .attr("in", "SourceGraphic");

   var field = svg.selectAll("g")
     .data(dataset)
     .enter().append("g");

   field.append("path").attr("class", "progress").attr("filter", "url(#dropshadow)")

   field.append("path").attr("class", "bg")
     .style("fill", function (d) {
      return colors[d.index];
     })
     .style("opacity", 0.2)
     .attr("d", background);
      
      field.append('marker')
            .attr('id', 'marker');

   field.append("text").attr('class','icon');


   if(singleArcView){

    field.append("text").attr('class','goal').text("OF 600 CALS").attr("transform","translate(0,50)");
    field.append("text").attr('class','completed').attr("transform","translate(0,0)");

   }
      

   d3.transition().duration(1750).each(update);

   function update() {
    field = field
      .each(function (d) {
       this._value = d.percentage;
      })
      .data(dataset)
      .each(function (d) {
       d.previousValue = this._value;
      });
        
         field.select("path.progress").transition().duration(1750).delay(function (d, i) {
     return i * 20
    })
      .ease("elastic")
      .attrTween("d", arcTween)
      .style("fill", function (d) {
       if(d.index===0){
        return "url(#gradient)"
       }
       return colors[d.index];
      });

    field.select("text.icon").text(function (d) {
     return d.icon;
    }).attr("transform", function (d) {
       return "translate(10," + -(150 - d.index * (40 + gap)) + ")"

      });

    field.select("text.completed").text(function (d) {
     return Math.round(d.percentage /100 * 600);
    });

        
  
    setTimeout(update, 2000);

   }

   function arcTween(d) {
    var i = d3.interpolateNumber(d.previousValue, d.percentage);
    return function (t) {
     d.percentage = i(t);
     return arc(d);
    };
   }
             d3.selectAll('.bg').each(function(d,i){
      d3.select(this).on('mouseover',function(){
        console.log(    d3.select(this).style('fill'))
      })})
    d3.selectAll('.icon').each(function(d,i){
      d3.select(this).on('mouseover',function(){
        console.log('ok')
      })
      
    })
  }


  build(ranDataset);
  build(ranDataset2,true);


 })()
```

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #000000;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;

}
.icon{
  font-family:fontawesome;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:30px;

}
.goal,.completed{
  font-family: 'Roboto','Myriad Set Pro', 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  fill:white;
  text-anchor:middle;
}
.goal{
  font-size: 30px;


}
.completed{
  font-size: 95px;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bm-w/d3/master/d3.js"></script>
```

Comment: when I apply this code, I get ` this.addEventListener is not a function` error. Did I miss anything?

Comment: try change the javascript on my code snipset and replace the https://codepen.io/zhaoyi0113/pen/mpzPjw you give me, if it not error, it must be on your local code

Comment: Thanks, could you let me know why you do `d3.select(this)` inside the each function?

Comment: that can be read as select all icon class and each of selected element do this, it like d3.select(#id) but i using .each so it be d3.select (this)